# How do I even edit Partials in TYPO3?

Tags: typo3, partials

Currently I´m in a internship for Web Development. So far I only worked with Wordpress or wrote Websites from scratch but now I´m working with TYPO3 for the first time.
I got the task to find out how to edit the header menu partial, but I don´t even know how to start or how to find the right answers on the internet. I´ve been sitting here for a few hours now, typing different questions into google, but I still don´t understand anything. =~=;

Does someone here have a suggestion where to find the answer for it or maybe explain it to me themself? ^^;

Comment: docs.typo3.org would be a good start.

Comment: e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R2udiLCy_YI (there are more tutorials in the TYPO3 YouTube channel)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your TYPO3 version (you may add a tag to your question) you can consult the manuals:
(my links are for version 11, you may switch the TYPO3 version of the manual on that pages):

[FLUID](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/11.5/en-us/ApiOverview/Fluid/Index.html)

Which leads to [FLUIDTEMPLATE](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/11.5/en-us/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/Index.html#cobj-fluidtemplate) and the [site package](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-sitepackage/11.5/en-us/Index.html) where you can find more information about templates and how you can add your own version of a template.

in general:

- find the template(1),
- copy the template file,
- edit the copy,
- add the path to your copy to the search-path for that template

(1) Template files are differentiated into Layout, Template, Partial